# Kubernetes - calico IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD impossible to set

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I want to force the interface, setting the `IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD`:

```
$ kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n calico-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=ens192
  daemonset.apps/calico-node env updated
```

But nothing happens:

```
$ kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n calico-system --list | grep IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
  IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=first-found
```

Answer (score 1):

On my cluster, running this:

```
kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=vbmgt0
```

from the control node did the trick as expected.

Are you running kubectl from the proper node ?

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node-n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=ens192 (replace with your interface)
```

[Check SS for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpI8f.png)

Restart calico pod after running this command and it should work fine as it will now use your desired interface.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it via tigera-operator like this:

```
kind: Installation
apiVersion: operator.tigera.io/v1
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: tigera-operator
spec:
  calicoNetwork:
    nodeAddressAutodetectionV4:
      cidrs:
        - "10.44.0.0/22"
```

At this example node interial Ips are at 10.44.0.0/22 CIDR.